# Cancel previous asynchronous .load() requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some javascript code that works as follows:

```
function updateResults() {
    var user_input = $('input:text').val();

    user_input = encodeURIComponent(user_input);

    div1.html('').load(cog_url); // Just displays a spinning cog while results load
    div2.html('').load(cog_url); // Just displays a spinning cog while results load
    div3.html('').load(cog_url); // Just displays a spinning cog while results load

    $.when(
        div1.html('').load("api/method1?input=" + user_input),
        div2.html('').load("api/method2?input=" + user_input),
        div3.html('').load("api/method3?input=" + user_input)
    ).done(function () {
        return true;
    });
}
```

The API methods just return HTML which contains the desired results to be rendered in the target divs. This all works relatively well, but when I submit multiple times to the system the previous requests don't get canceled so I get a string of responses and the divs keep getting reloaded with all the requests that were sent in order. I'd like to have it so that just the latest request is returned if the previous one(s) hasn't finished. Any suggestions as to how to do this? I'd like to keep the asynchronous aspect of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it with `.load`. You will have to use the `.ajax` or one of the shorthand methods (*in this case `.get` should do*).

So you need to add the Promises to an array and use for the `when` and also iterate over it and abort when re-calling the function.

something like this

```
var calls = [];
function updateResults() {
    var user_input = $('input:text').val(),
        apiQuery = {input: user_input};

    div1.empty().load(cog_url); // Just displays a spinning cog while results load
    div2.empty().load(cog_url); // Just displays a spinning cog while results load
    div3.empty().load(cog_url); // Just displays a spinning cog while results load

    calls.forEach(function(call){call.abort();});
    calls = [];
    calls.push( $.get('api/method1',apiQuery) );
    calls.push( $.get('api/method2',apiQuery) );
    calls.push( $.get('api/method3',apiQuery) );

    $.when.apply($, calls).done(function (result1, result2, result3) {
        div1.html(result1);
        div2.html(result2);
        div3.html(result3);

        return true;
    });
}
```

---

Additionally do not use `.html('')`, there is a `.empty()` method that does that. Also, if you pass an object as the parameters to the ajax calls it gets encoded by default (*no need to manually encode the input*)

Comment: probably need to  empty calls array also after aborts?

Comment: I ended up doing 
`calls.push( $.get('api/method1',apiQuery).done(function (result1) {
        div1.html(result1);
    })); );`

So that the other components wouldn't wait on the results of each other since they aren't all timed the same. Thanks for the help though! Apparently, the .get() is async by default.

Comment: @DamianJ all ajax calls are async by default (*the first A in AJAX means asynchronous*). And yes, you did the right thing, if you needed them to appear as they load and not wait all to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a sort of flag to determine if it is the last request ?

By example :

```
function updateResults(isLastRequest) {
    var user_input = $('input:text').val();

    user_input = encodeURIComponent(user_input);

    div1.html('').load(cog_url); // Just displays a spinning cog while results load
    div2.html('').load(cog_url); // Just displays a spinning cog while results load
    div3.html('').load(cog_url); // Just displays a spinning cog while results load

    $.when(
        if(isLastRequest){
            div1.html('').load("api/method1?input=" + user_input),
            div2.html('').load("api/method2?input=" + user_input),
            div3.html('').load("api/method3?input=" + user_input)

        }
    ).done(function () {
        return true;
    });
}
```

Does it help ?